# Problems open image from hard drive

Tags: jpeg, mjpeg

I found a file with jpg extension, but metadata says mjpeg. However, i can not open the file. I have the hex code for the file and I cant find jpeg header in the hex. I searched for other common file types headers without success.

please help me, i really need to find out whats in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly file is `corrupted` or saved `non-standard format`. Try following:

1. Try to open with several other `image viewers`.
2. Try to convert the file to different format using `conversion tools`, there are a lot online available
3. You may also consider to `data recovery paid services`
4. If none of them works, that means your file `was never saved properly` from the first time.